# How to Copy files between two Linux partitions which is located in server from my local windows machine?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, file-transfer, partition-copy

I want to know how to Copy files between  two Linux partitions  which is mounted in server .  Currently I am using my local windows  machine to do it but want to make automatic by using commands from command prompt . I tried ssh , scp, wscp etc it throws  error connection refused own port 22 I try to change port but it is not taken place properly. 
So is there any better possibilities  to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you SSH to the server?

Comment: yes but that too not worked for me..